# Tips for non-EU citizens seeking employment in the UK

Tags: interviewing, united-kingdom

I am a non-EU citizen, living and working in the UK.

As time goes by, several opportunities have presented themselves to me to move ahead in my career. Whether it's a recruiter contacting me online, or through job applications, I've gotten the chance to do many interviews which lead to job offers.

However, I always eventually run into a major hurdle:

- "Congratulations! We would like to make you an offer. But first, we need more info. Where are you from?"
- "North America."
- "Oh. Unfortunately, we reserve those sponsorships for senior positions only. Thanks for your interest in us!"

This conversation takes place *even if I mention my status during the interview rounds that lead to the offer*. It seems like my interviewers never communicate this to the recruiters/HR. This is particularly frustrating, especially since those interviews cost me vacation time, in addition to a hefty amount of personal time to prepare after-hours. It seems like I've landed in the only company that gives out sponsorships to non-EU citizens! And it's not limited to a specific company type/size.

So, what is the best way to manage this? Should I just accept this as "how things are" and just keep applying? Would it be better to move back to North America? Is there a specific company type/size I should target in my applications?

Comment: I was talking to a friend based in London who said his company was the same. I can't offer any specific advice, but apparently it's actually included in the work policy. They don't offer jobs to foreigners because they are "concerned employees will use it as a stepping stone into the country". Keep trying, there **must** be an exclusion to this rule. It seems absurd to me as a Canadian that this is even a thing.

Comment: @Ballbreaker that sounds interesting, but I'm already working in the country, so do you think that this still applies?

Comment: Oh sorry, I must have passed over that aspect and assumed it was your first opportunity for employment in the UK. My knowledge for this topic is limited, so hopefully someone will give you a real answer here.

Comment: @Ballbreaker, it's a 'thing' because the sponsorship process is bureaucratic and expensive, and the firm is (to an extent) responsible if the employee abuses the scheme to cheat on immigration status. Also because it may be necessary to prove that no suitably qualified applicant could be found within the EU (eg by advertising the post for a set period of time and having nobody suitable apply), which might simply not be the case. Surely Canada has immigration and work permit laws too?

Comment: If your working you presumably have the right to work in the UK  - so where is the issue - you don't need to say your nationality just that you have the right to work in the UK

Comment: @Pepone: If I understand correctly, OP has the right to work in the UK only for an employer which sponsors their visa - which their current employer is doing. So he/she can only change job if the new employer is also willing to sponsor their visa.

Comment: @AwesomeSauce ah would have helped if they had said that :-)

Answer (score 5):

@AwesomeSauce, how explicitly are you stating your status? It's not enough just to say what country you're from, because there are many people who originate from other countries living in the UK as British or EU citizens with full UK employment rights.

Most firms will assume that if you're applying for a UK job then you already have the right to work (for any employer) in the UK. Hiring managers outside of the HR department may not even realise that your circumstances require the firm to do anything special in order to hire you - this is not a situation which all managers have necessarily encountered.

To be completely clear I'd suggest saying:

"I do not currently have permission to work in the UK for anyone except my current employer; your firm would need to provide visa sponsorship for me.

Does your firm have a sponsor licence, and would you be able to sponsor me for a Tier 2 *(or whatever tier is appropriate for you and for the job)* UK visa?

Could you check before I come for interview that you'd be able to do that?"

and then get them to come back to you in writing to confirm before you attend the interview.

When you're applying for jobs, bear in mind that small/new firms don't usually have the HR experience and resources (or the time, the desire or the need) to register for a sponsor licence - you probably need a big corporation.

Summary info:
https://www.gov.uk/uk-visa-sponsorship-employers/overview

Detailed info: https://www.gov.uk/government/collections/sponsorship-information-for-employers-and-educators

Shortage occupation list: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/486107/Shortage_Occupation_List_-_November_2015.pdf You are more likely to find a firm which can sponsor you if the job you're applying for is on this list. The list changes periodically. For some (mostly IT) roles the company itself must meet certain requirements in terms of size and ownership - see the final page of the list.

For even more detailed info, see [Tier 2 and 5 of the Points Based System,
Guidance for Sponsors (UK Visas and Immigration)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/477792/Tier_25_guidance_11-15_word_v1_0doc.pdf). The fact that this is a 176-page document gives you an idea why many employers are not keen to perform visa sponsorship unless they see a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is quite insightful. To answer the questions you raise: I don't hold UK or any EU citizenship, I'm a citizen of the US/Canada. Only applied to large corporations (big banks, financial services, and your Googles and Dropboxes). There were many interviews in which I bring this up at the very first round of interviews (as well as the subsequent stages), and I'm *still* allowed to advance till the end.

Answer (score 2):

It's not at all unusual for the HR department and the people who the interviews to work in completely separate silos. Often HR has no interest in the process until someone is actually hired.

Perhaps if your interviewees are not communicating this to HR, you might be able to do so yourself. When you are interviewed for the first time, or even prior to the interview, ask for the appropriate HR contact who deals with hiring issues.

If asked why, you can simply state your concerns as you have done in other interviews, and want to confirm there would be no policy barriers to prevent you from working there.